# Добавление нового типа объекта в фабрику

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется небольшое семейство экранных форм. Для каждой с формы определён интерфейс **IForm**.

```
class IForm
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     IForm() = default;
     virtual ~IForm() = default;
protected:
    virtual void setModel(IModel* model) = 0;
    virtual void setController(IController* ctrl) = 0;
};
```

Интерфейс реализуют:

**SimpleForm**

```
class SimpleForm
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     SimpleForm() = delete;
     SimpleForm(IModel* model, IController* ctrl);
     virtual ~SimpleForm() = default;
protected:
    virtual void setModel(IModel* model);
    virtual void setController(IController* ctrl);
};
```

Допустим есть ещё какие-то реализации этого интерфейса, имеющие такой же конструктор, как и у SimpleForm.

Так как заранее неизвестно, какие формы понадобятся клиенту, организуем шаблонный класс-создатель с фабричным методом.

Описываем интерфейс:

```
class IFormFactory
{
public:
    IFormFactory() = default;
    virtual ~IFormFactory() = default;
    virtual IForm* createForm(IModel* m, IController* ctrl) = 0;
};
```

Создаем шаблонную реализацию:

```
template <typename T>
class FormFactory : public IFormFactory
{
public:
    FormFactory () = default;
    IForm* createForm(IModel* m, IController* ctrl) override
    {
        return new T(m, ctrl);
    }
};
```

Всё было бы хорошо, но потребовалось создать совсем особую форму -  **SpecialForm**. Она расширяет интерфейс IForm, но конструктор SpecialForm содержит пару дополнительных параметров:

```
SpecialForm(IModel* m, IController* ctrl, IModelReestr* mr, IControllerReestr* cr);
```

IModelReestr, IControllerReestr - являются реестром всех доступных в модуле моделей и контроллеров

Вот тут возникает проблема -  текущая реализация фабрики не позволяет создавать формы типа SpecialForm. Я думал сделать в фабрике перегруженный метод create с учётом дополнительных параметров конструктора, но для остальных форм этот метод будет не нужен. 
Так как IModelReestr и IControllerReestr содержат в себе другие модели и контроллеры, то тут возможно стоило бы применить паттерн Композиция. Да, тогда я смогу унифицировать входящие параметры конструктора, но стоит ли так усложнять архитектуру? Ведь по сути получает просто оболочка, которая уничтожается в конструкторе конкретной формы при получении нужно модели или контроллера. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: "усложнять архитектуру?" на этот вопрос наверное можете ответить, только вы, т.к. по тексту попроса не понятно, куда это встраивается и где будет использоваться. Как вариант можете передать в метод структуру с заполнеными полями. Для обычной формы поля mr и cr могут быть нулевыми.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить немножко шаблонов!

```
template <class... Args>
class IFormFactory
{
public:
    IFormFactory() = default;
    virtual ~IFormFactory() = default;
    virtual IForm* createForm(Args... args) = 0;
};

template <typename T, class ...Args>
class FormFactory : public IFormFactory<Args...>
{
public:
    FormFactory () = default;
    IForm* createForm(Args... args) override
    {
        return new T(args...);
    }
};
```

Также для удобства можно определить:

```
template <class T>
using SimpleFactory = FormFactory<T, IModel*, IController*>; // от неё наследуем стандартные фабрики, чтобы везде не писать IModel*, IController*
```

Comment: Понял, можно сделать ещё больше шаблонов, но как нужную фабрику инстанцировать в коде? FormFactory<SimpleForm> factory(); factory.createForm(//список параметров); даёт ошибку. Оно и понятно, что второй аргумент шаблона список пустых параметров.

Comment: `FormFactory<SimpleForm, IModel*, IController*> factory(m, c)` или `SimpleFactory<SimpleForm> factory(m, c)`